# django rest framework serializer allows extra fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a serializer for a view. It's not a ModelSerializer. This serializer contains the possible fields to send in the request. I have noticed that in the request I can send fields that don't appear in the serializer and it passes the serializer validation.

For example, this the serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    users_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), required=False)

    class Meta:

        fields = [
            'days',
            'users_list'
        ]
```

In the View I do this:

```
class UserValuesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I can see that the serializer is called, and when sending wrong values types I do get an exception, but when sending fields that don't appear in the serializer 'fields' it also passes the validation.

For example:

```
data = {
        'days': '7',
        'users_list': ['1234', '123456'],
        'some_key': 'some_value'
    }
```

How can I enforce the possible fields to send from the serializer?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, why do you want to change it? The extra data is simply going to be discarded

Comment: @AayushAgrawal Basically I would like to go over all the received fields and add them to some json field in the view without validating them. I assumed that this behavior is given by the serializer. i.e when I process the request in the view I can be sure that all fields are what I expected, and currently those fields are found in the view request.data

Comment: I see that the problem is that I'm using request.data instead of serializer.data!